# Grant "IIS_IUSRS" Full Access to the Root of your Website

Tags: windows-8, permissions, iis

I am setting up an environment  using Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and come across the instruction, "Grant "IIS_IUSRS" full access to the root of your website" with the following note:

> If you are running your Anonymous Authentication as ApplicationPoolIdentity for > your local site (rather than IUSR), this step may not be needed.

I do not know how to grant these permissions (at an elementary level) and I do not know how to check the settings in the mentioned comment. I have the website set up - so that shouldn't be an issue.

Where do I go to check the settings and how do I grant access to  users?

I am also working to develop the guide further so that the person after me is better able to take these steps.

Comment: I may need help fleshing out the specifics of my question - this is all new to me. So, please, ask away.

Comment: Your title mentioned IIS6, yet you've tagged the question Windows 8, so I'm confused. Especially since the IIS_IUSRS access needs are different under newer Windows/IIS versions.  Also, can you provide the source of the comment you're quoting?

Comment: I can't unfortunately provide the source as it is an internal document. It may not be IIS 6.0 (I do have that on my computer - as we have to support older versions of an application). I am totally confused - as I literally have no idea what I am doing. The quotations are the extent of the comments on this step.